# :hover not working in IE6 after DD_belated transparent .PNG fix (help?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am using dd_belatedpng to fix transparent png in ie6 but.
but attaching dd_belatedpng.js rollover/ :hover not working in ie6.

```
 a {background:url(images/border.png) 0 top no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; }

 a:hover {background:url(images/border2.png) 0 bottom no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px;}
```

Comment: In IE6, `:hover` only works on `a` elements. If `li:hover` worked before you added DD_belatedPNG, then you must be using some other JavaScript to *make* it work. What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`:hover` does not work in IE6 on any element other than `<a>`.

You can try to fix this using [hover.htc](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html).